# Add Conditional multiple column filter on datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

I have used datatable for display list of my data and I have below fields in that.
ID, First Name, Last Name, Positions, Team, Salary, fpts, Values, Exps.

And I want one filter button in which the data can be filled with below conditions.

```
fpts >= 10 && fpts <= 50000 && Salary >= 10 && Salary <= 5000 && Values >= 0.05 && Values <= 5.20
```

Is there any way to do this in datatable?

Please help me in this concern.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you talking about server side or client side datatable? add more info like fiddle or codepen.

Comment: Not from the database. Need it from the client side. I have all the data loaded in my datatable and need to filter it dynamically.

Comment: then you have to use extra textbox as shown in [this](https://datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/range_filtering.html).

Comment: add code in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).. and share the link, so that i can help you to solve your problem.